# How do is show product by user role in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created 4 different user roles(Administrator, Designer, Blogger, Team) in WordPress with different privileges. Each user can post his own product and my requirement is I have created 4 pages for show products according user role.

Example: Supposed I logged as administrator and I add a product.after logout when i click on administrator page then I want to show only that product which have posted by administrator. Like administrator if I logged as designer then after logout at designer page should be show only those products which posted by designer. Same process for other user roles.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy in wordpress. Check with this code.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if($current_user->roles[0]=='administrator'){
//Admin code
}elseif($current_user->roles[0]=='designer'){
//designer code
}
elseif($current_user->roles[0]=='blogger'){
//blogger code
}
elseif($current_user->roles[0]=='team'){
//team code
}
```

Comment: Hello Hemnath,

Thanks for help.
The above code can be used those time when any user logged in but I want to show product without any logged in user means I want to show all those products which posted by designer.

Thanks